# I perceive fuel in my bore hole water

Tags: geology, groundwater, pollution

Since I am from the Niger delta, where crude oil is mostly seen ... when we pump water and I try drinking it, it reeks of fuel ... how can I confirm it to be crude locally before alerting the oil company?

Comment: If it is natural seepage , I doubt an oil company would have much interest. However they should have the ability to determine if it is seepage, refined product or a leak of produced oil from piping.

Comment: Sampling for trace hydrocarbons in water is a fairly standard for commercial water quality laboratories.  There are oil detection test strips available that allow quick field assessments e.g. https://www.mn-net.com/qualitative-oil-test-paper-90760,  if you can find local suppliers.  Local universities or NGOs might be able to help.